# Mobile devices: get screen area size and position with css, not just viewport's

Tags: html, css, screen, viewport

This question states what I took months to figure out:

[is mobile viewport size larger than screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341562/is-mobile-viewport-size-larger-than-screen-size)

That is, the contents rendered in the screen area of mobile browsers sometimes are just part of the viewport. They are the same only when the zoom-out specified by meta viewport tag is the current zoom value.

Some problems arise with this model, eg: css-sticky headers do not appear in the screen and centered elements (relative to the viewport) are not centered relative to the screen. The final user loses some information depending on the zoom.

I could try to solve those positioning problems if there were some css values that refer to the screen area size and position. Which are them?

Or, at least, is it possible to get the visible screen rectangle with javascript?

**EDIT1**

I checked for changes in properties directly under window, window.screen, document and document.documentElement while moving the screen position, but no changes were detected other than when the true viewport needed to move because the screen moved out of its current bounds.

**EDIT2**

First answer do not address the problem. I put the code to run and console.log the result each 1 second here:

http://wlee.eu5.net/viewport.php

Open it on Chrome simulating mobile devices and scroll a little. Even though the screen has moved, the logged dimensions will not change until the screen reaches the true viewport limits.

You can see it looking to the "I am centered" text, which is always in the center of the viewport, but not screen. Also, the viewport has red outlines.

I think mobile browsers take a piece of the viewport to show into the screen, and that's precisely this piece's position that I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! It comes under **window.visualViewport**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VisualViewport

The method JSON.stringify were not able to get visualViewport properties, so I couldn't watch them changing while scrolling the page.

### Summary

visualViewport.pageLeft/Top gets the scrolled viewport relative to the page.

visualViewport.offsetLeft/Top gets the screen rectangle relative to the viewport. This rectangle is what mobile browsers show on screen when you zoom the page, which happens without changing the page scroll.

No css found for this one. I'll keep searching.

Answer (score 0):

If a webpage is supposed to adapt to mobile devices, it would be a great practice to add a `viewport` meta tag to your page, so that your viewport will be represented equally across all devices. You can read more about this meta tag [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

There are `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, and `vmax` size units in CSS which are related to the viewport parameters of the user's device. If you would like to make an element adapt to the size of the user's viewport, then specify its size in these units instead of pixels or percentages. You can read more about using these units [here](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/).

If you want to go beyond just scaling an object proportionally to the current viewport, you can of course retrieve the viewport information by using JavaScript. Here is a function that does exactly that:

```
function GetCurrentViewportLocation() {
    const xOffset = window.pageXOffset,
          yOffset = window.pageYOffset,
          vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0),
          vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);
    
    return {
        topLeft: { x: xOffset, y: yOffset },
        topRight: { x: xOffset + vw, y: yOffset },
        bottomLeft: { x: xOffset, y: yOffset + vh },
        bottomRight: { x: xOffset + vw, y: yOffset + vh },
    }
}
```

Zooming the screen in updates the coordinates accordingly.

Comment: Does not work. It gets the viewport position, not screen inside viewport.

Comment: I'll try to make a page that shows the problem, which may have been misunderstood.